# Hot swap SATA drive

Tags: windows-8

With Windows 7, say you have these internal drives

```
C:  main drive with Windows
D:  extra drive with files
```

If you have the computer open, you can plug and unplug `D:` just like an external USB drive. However I have noticed with Windows 8 if you plug in a new drive it will not be recognized unless you restart.

How can I set Windows 8 to recognize a new drive without rebooting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure hot plugging is enabled on the SATA controller you are using (probably the one soldered on the motherboard, you can configure it on your UEFI configuration panel from Windows directly if your constructor provide a tool for it, or by rebooting on the UEFI configuration GUI)

You may want to check if your SATA controller driver are correctly installed too.

If you are using a thunderbolt device, there's some issues with this and you may be unable to do anything about it.

On a side note, don't forget to use the windows unplug tray icon before unplugging to ensure no data is lost when removing the drive.

Answer (score 0):

I know some people are having issues with the Intel sata drivers causing issues. If this is the case I would download the trial of http://zentimo.com/ and see if that fixes your issue:

> **Zentimo** offers a new way to manage your USB & eSATA devices. While it solves many external drive related problems in Windows, it also gives more control and makes working with external drives fun & pleasure.